# SharePoint navigation forgets where it is

Tags: office-365, navigation

I have noticed that when I click to a list or document library in SharePoint Office 365 the navigation does not reflect where I am, for example I have click on the passwords list and then click on a different view the navigation shows me in Business Intelligence.

How do I fix this?

[image]